# How to make menu buttons in Java?

Tags: java

I've made text appear inside of this menu I made with the Rectangle class. I want to know if I can make it so the text is able to be selected, and you can choose your selection with the keyboard arrows and then press Enter and it will then preform the next action. Here's what I have so far:

```
public Rectangle menuBorder;
    public Rectangle menu;
    BufferedImage character;
    private java.awt.Point characterLocation;
    private java.awt.Point borderLocation;
    private java.awt.Point menuLocation;
    public int charW = 24;
    public int charH = 36;
    public int borderW = 210;
    public int borderH = 80;
    public int menuW = 190;
    public int menuH = 60;


    public boolean right = false;
    public boolean left = false;
    public boolean up = false;
    public boolean down = false;

    public Keying(Display f, Images i) throws IOException
    {
        character = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("starting mon.png"));
        menuBorder = new Rectangle(10, 10, borderW, borderH);
        menu = new Rectangle(10, 10, menuW, menuH);
        characterLocation = new Point(175, 100);
        borderLocation = new Point(175, 270);
        menuLocation = new Point(185, 280);

//...


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        g.drawImage(character, characterLocation.x, characterLocation.y, this);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(borderLocation.x, borderLocation.y, borderW, borderH);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(menuLocation.x, menuLocation.y, menuW, menuH);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("Battle", 190, 305);
        g.drawString("Feed", 320, 305);
        g.drawString("Pet", 200, 335);
        g.drawString("Age", 325, 335);
    }
//...
```

Comment: DO NOT call methods that change the state of the component from within ANY paint method.  Painting should paint the CURRENT state and should DO NOTHING that might cause that state to mutate during the paint process.  Doing so WILL cause an infinite loop of repaint requests which WILL consume your PC until it is sucked into a black hole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, see my first comment about painting...

You will need some kind of "state" variable so you can determine what state you should paint, this could be achieved through the use of some kind of [`ListSelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html).

You will probably need a `MouseListener` and a `MouseMotionListener` to monitor the state of the mouse, see [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

You'll also probably want to take a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Of course, you could just use a `JList` and save yourself the hassle...see [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: Okay, thanks! But as far as Key Bindings go, I have the display for this game with the character and the menu right below it. Just to test I made the keys make the character move, but instead I want the arrow keys to move the selection of the menu items (like in pokemon, where there's somewhat of an outline in a rectangle of what is being selected). I don't want to use JList because it appears to show up in a GUI style instead of being inside the same display. Sorry for the lengthy comment :/

Comment: Use key bindings and define the focus level they require to be active. Make sure the components they are attached to are focusable and switch focus with requestFocusInWindow

Comment: Alright cool :) I'll read up on it and give it a shot, but if I don't reply to thank you it's probably because my computer created a black hole.